# Implement Hypernetworks in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to implement a [Hypernetwork](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.09106.pdf), so a network `B` that creates the weights for another network `A`. So network `A` does a convolution, but instead of using its own weights, it takes the output of network `B`. `B` creates different weights for every input.

I thought about using a lambda layer and just define the function like this:

```
def conv2d(tensors):
    import keras.backend as K
    image_tensor, template_tensor = tensors
    template_tensor = K.expand_dims(template_tensor, -1)  # kernel must be of shape (k1, k2, in_channel, out_channel)
    return K.conv2d(image_tensor, template_tensor, padding="same")
```

The problem is the batch dimension. `template_tensor` has shape `[None, kernel_1, kernel_2, in_channels, out_channels]` but `K.conv2d` expects a kernel with shape `[kernel_1, kernel_2, in_channels, out_channels]`.

So it would be good to have something like this:

```
def conv2d(tensors):
    import keras.backend as K
    image_tensor, template_tensor = tensors
    template_tensor = K.expand_dims(template_tensor, -1)  # kernel must be of shape (k1, k2, in_channel, out_channel)

    out_tensor = np.zeros_like(image_tensor)
    for i in template_tensor.shape[0]:
        out_tensor[i] = conv2d(image_tensor[i], template_tensor[i], padding="same") 


    return out_tensor
```

or implement it in any other way (e.g. as a Layer).

Thanks

Comment: If you are using TF 1.x, you can use the custom getter pattern for parameter generation (see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275253/tensorflow-2-0-keras-layers-with-custom-tensors-as-variables). There is no obvious way to generalize it TF 2.0 yet.